# Какой знак поставить перед вводным словом в сложном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, сложное-предложение, вводное-слово

Как выбрать и объяснить **знак перед вводным словом:**

***Ждать пришлось недолго:** маленькое изображение Принца в полный рост мотыльком затрепетало над синей татуировкой, связь была неустойчивая, с помехами и частым пропаданием цвета (?) **возможно, на линии шалила магнитная буря** или же где‑то неподалеку от кафе работало мощное устройство, некачественное и плохо отлаженное.* (Из художественной литературы.)

**Пояснение**

Здесь  уже есть **двоеточие** (обозначение бессоюзной связи), поэтому приходится выбирать знак.

Ну и общая грамматическая структура предложения какая? Может, есть **другой вариант** оформления предложения с таким содержанием?

Как вы думаете?
Спасибо.

Comment: А почему _Принц_, а не _принц_?

Comment: В книге это имя собственное.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просмотрел **семь источников**: [РИДЛИ](https://readli.net/chitat-online/?b=109926&pg=2), [livelib.ru](https://www.livelib.ru/book/21327/readpart-ahtimag-mihail-babkin/%7E2), [rulit.me](https://www.rulit.me/books/ahtimag-read-60676-2.html), [KNIGA ONLINE](https://kniga-online.com/books/fantastika-i-fjentezi/fjentezi/page-3-53150-mihail-babkin-ahtimag.html), [LibCat.Ru](https://libcat.ru/knigi/fantastika-i-fjentezi/detektivnaya-fantastika/329758-4-mihail-babkin-ahtimag.html#text), [ЛИТМИР](https://litmir.club/br/?b=85204&p=2), [BOOKBEAR](https://my.bookbear.net/library/book/13483519325/online-read/?p=11). В них предложение из книги «Ахтимаг» Михаила Бабкина выглядит так:

*Ждать пришлось недолго: маленькое изображение Принца, в полный рост, мотыльком затрепетало над синей татуировкой; связь была неустойчивая, с помехами и частым пропаданием цвета – возможно, на линии шалила магнитная буря или же где-то неподалёку от кафешки работало мощное колдовское устройство, некачественное и плохо отлаженное.*

А вот, например, на сайте [6lib.ru](https://www.6lib.ru/books/read/ahtimag-25085?page=9) в этом предложении перед "***возможно***" стоят запятая и тире (или это единый знак?), а также не обособлено "***в полный рост***", перед словом "***связь***" стоит просто запятая (как у вас в вопросе), вместо "***кафешки***" – "***кафе***":

*Ждать пришлось недолго: маленькое изображение Принца в полный рост мотыльком затрепетало над синей татуировкой, связь была неустойчивая, с помехами и частым пропаданием цвета, – возможно, на линии шалила магнитная буря или же где-то неподалеку от кафе работало мощное колдовское устройство, некачественное и плохо отлаженное.*

Более корректным мне видится **первый вариант** оформления.
**Точка с запятой** отделяет практически не связанные друг с другом смысловые части, между ними можно поставить и точку. Перед **тире**, думаю, нет необходимости ставить запятую: однородные предложения с общим вводным словом "***возможно***" поясняют, почему *связь была неустойчивая, с помехами и частым пропаданием цвета*, и относятся только к этой части. А запятая с тире графически порвут эти отношения.

Comment: Да, ваш (первый)  вариант покруче будет, мне он больше нравится: все четко, все на месте. А если блоками решать, то у нас будет два блока, разделенных точкой с запятой.   В первом блоке БСП, а втором тоже блок с тремя основами, тире выбрано правильно, единый знак не подойдет. В первой части обособление  несогласованного определения тоже нужно.  Все как по нотам, my respect and delight, in a word!

Comment: @Sharon  Очень рад, что всё сошлось! Спасибо за вопрос!

Comment: Да, вот и доверяй после этого редакторам книг, все у них по-разному. А у меня два сильных знака (двоеточие и единый знак) никак не могли поделить территорию.

Comment: @Sharon А у вас какая версия? Можете дать ссылку? Или вообще бумажная? // И как вы всё успеваете – и здесь постоянно,  и читаете ещё?

Comment: У меня бумажная книга 2005 года, я ее люблю и иногда перечитываю для удовольствия.   Там интересный мир описан: летают на драконах, а технологии крутые.  Да еще волшебства хватает. Главный герой – сыщик, ищет пропавшего принца, почти Гамлета.  Королева попросила, а ее новый претендент в мужья прошипел ему на ухо: "Если ты, св..., притащишь назад этого убл...а, то тебе не жить." Хорошая завязка сюжета.   А читаю, как и где придется...